# Which parameters to use when creation a new ActiveXObject for support the older browsers

Tags: javascript, activexobject, get-request

I want to create a new GET request and support also older browsers.
I have the following code, but do NOT understand which application name and type to specify. For example: new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
What should I write instead of Microsoft.XMLHTTP?

```
 function loadDoc() {
     var xhttp;
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
       // code for modern browsers
       xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
       } else {
       // code for IE6, IE5
       xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }
     xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
       }
     };
     xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
     xhttp.send();
   }
```

Comment: What makes you think you need something other than `Microsoft.XMLHTTP`?

Comment: Separately: Even IE8 supports `XMLHttpRequest`. There's really no need to support anything older than IE8 (and even IE8 is nearly dead, thankfully).

Comment: Also, why are you re-inventing the wheel? This particular problem has been solved so often in the past that you can pick from multiple well-matured and well-tested solutions. You really should not be writing this code at all.

Comment: I saw different examples like:
  var xml = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument");
  var xsl = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");

So I didn't know what to use? Microsoft? MSXML2 ? and more..